# Which dance move are you totally down with?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

I was filling a funny test and this was one of the questions:

Which dance move are you totally down with?

What does "totally down with" means?

Is it positive or negative?

Comment: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=down%20with

Comment: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=down%20with%20that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's positive, and quite colloquial. A more formal way to phrase this would be “which dance style are you very comfortable with?”

Here are the relevant definitions and examples from Wiktionary:

*[totally](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/totally)*:

> (*degree, colloquial*) Very; extremely.
>
> *That was **totally** wicked!*

*[down](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/down#English) with*; also *down to*:

> (*not comparable, US, slang*) Comfortable with, accepting of.
>
> *Are you **down to** hang out at the mall, Jamal?*
>
> *As long as you're **down with** helping me pick a phone, Jack.*

Comment: Note on usage: As with most slang, what used to be an expression used only by the young and the hip is now commonly heard from the mouths of corporate executives and yoga moms.  Saying you are "down with" something is perfectly fine, as long as you don't mind sounding old and out of it  :)

Comment: @Andrew Further note on usage: since this bit of argot originated in the Black community and was then adopted by White kids who wanted to appear _down with_ all things hiphop (an effort that fails because, well, mirror don't lie) the speaker should not mind sounding _old, out of it, and pale._